# How to expand a div?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my div expand and "go down again" how can I do this, I have tried with various javascript but cant seem to make it work

my code is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Icyow

```
<div id="chatContainer">

    <div id="chatTopBar"></div>
    <div id="chatLineHolder"></div>

    <div id="chatBottomBar">


        <form id="submitForm" method="post" action="">
            <input id="chatText" name="chatText" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type here..." />
            <input type="submit" class="blueButton" value="Submit" style="visibility: hidden;" />
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post a relevant snippet of javascript code that you've tried into your question.

Comment: If you want an easy way to expand your element down and up, I would use jQuery's `.slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JavaScript code you need:

```
$('#chatTopBar').on("click", function() {
    $("#chatLineHolder, #chatBottomBar").slideToggle();
});
```

Here is the codepen fork: http://codepen.io/praneybehl/pen/JrvyK

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Note you can also use `.slideToggle()` for a nice effect: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vFbKp